# How to get iPhone Bluetooth adapter name in iOS programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing and application in which I need to show bluetooth information of the device. I av finally got some succes regarding bluetooth mac address but won't be able to get the device name. Is there any way to get the device name legally through some public api?

```
NSString*btMacAddr = @"Bt ";
BOOL                        success;
struct ifaddrs *            addrs;
const struct ifaddrs *      cursor;
const struct sockaddr_dl *  dlAddr;
const uint8_t *             base;

success = getifaddrs(&addrs) == 0;
if (success) {
    cursor = addrs;
    while (cursor != NULL) {
        if ( (cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK)
            && (((const struct sockaddr_dl *) cursor->ifa_addr)->sdl_type == IFT_ETHER)
            && (strcmp(cursor->ifa_name, "en0") == 0)) {
            dlAddr = (const struct sockaddr_dl *) cursor->ifa_addr;
            base = (const uint8_t *) &dlAddr->sdl_data[dlAddr->sdl_nlen];

            if (dlAddr->sdl_alen == 6) {
                //fprintf(stderr, ">>>             WIFI MAC ADDRESS: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", base[0], base[1], base[2], base[3], base[4], base[5]);
                //fprintf(stderr, ">>> IPHONE BLUETOOTH MAC ADDRESS: %02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x\n", base[0], base[1], base[2], base[3], base[4], base[5]+1);
                btMacAddr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Mac Address  :  %02x : %02x : %02x : %02x : %02x : %02x", base[0], base[1], base[2], base[3], base[4], base[5]+1];


            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR - len is not 6");
            }
        }
        cursor = cursor->ifa_next;
    }
    freeifaddrs(addrs);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the BT name of the iPhone running the app, or that of the device to which it is connecting?

Comment: BT name of the iPhone running the app

Comment: Hi @MuhammadUsman, could you please explain how you obtained the Bluetooth MAC Address?  I am looking for this information.

Comment: Hey @JuJoDi i have used the above piece of code to find the bluetooth mac address.

Comment: I tried your code on a iPhone5 with iOS7 but this won't give me the BT mac address WIFI MAC ADDRESS: 02:00:00:00:00:00
IPHONE BLUETOOTH MAC ADDRESS: 02:00:00:00:00:01
 Mac Address  :  02 : 00 : 00 : 00 : 00 : 01

Answer (score 1):

Then isn't it something like:
[[UIDevice currentDevice] name];

That gives the name of the iOS device like "Henriks iPhone"

Comment: Right but BT device name could be anything other than device name .

Comment: That's a good point, henrick. I assume this will be true in most cases, as I don't see a way for the user to change the BT device name. 

@V-Xtreme, are you sure the BT device name can be changed to something other than the UIDevice.name?

Answer (score 0):

It's not explicit in the documentation, but in the CBCentralManagerDelegate methods, such as [centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/translated_content/CBCentralManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManagerDelegate/centralManager%3adidDiscoverPeripheral%3aadvertisementData%3aRSSI%3a), one of the parameters being passed into the delegate is a CBPeripheral.

Interestingly enough, Apple doesn't list any official documentation for CBPeripheral, but if you look at the header file for CBPeripheral.h, it looks like there's a "`_name`" field that you might be able to extract out of there (for myself, the compiler didn't complain when I did "`peripheral.name`", as if it there was some property defined)

But then again, to verify my answer I tried downloading [Apple's CoreBluetooth Temperature Sensor sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TemperatureSensor/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012194) and ran it with a command of "`[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];`" on my iPhone 4S without much success (generating a "`CoreBluetooth[WARNING] <CBConcreteCentralManager: 0x2087fc00> is not powered on`" error even though Bluetooth was definitely set to *on* in the device settings).

Anyways, I hope my hints might actually help you out.

Comment: Sorry didnt ring the bell. Can u please explain it a bit more or may be show some example how to extract out of header?